# How to add specific text in between

Tags: notepad++, addition

This is an part of XML file.

What i have

```
<Layer Idx="65" Name="3D.A11_SA">
<OdbObj Mv="2" Sv="0">
<OdbRef>
</OdbRef>
</OdbObj>
<Name>3D.A11_SA</Name>
<Index>65</Index>
<Flags>Layer_Hidden</Flags>
<ModiTime>0</ModiTime>
<RegMemoTable MemoNumber="0" Mv="1" Sv="0"/>
<ConnectionClassId>1</ConnectionClassId>
```

What i want to have

```
<Layer Idx="65" Name="3D(II Phase).A11_SA">
<OdbObj Mv="2" Sv="0">
<OdbRef>
</OdbRef>
</OdbObj>
<Name>3D(II Phase).A11_SA</Name>
<Index>65</Index>
<Flags>Layer_Hidden</Flags>
<ModiTime>0</ModiTime>
<RegMemoTable MemoNumber="0" Mv="1" Sv="0"/>
<ConnectionClassId>1</ConnectionClassId>
```

I would like to insert a word `3D"**(II Phase)**".A11_SA` into a `name=` and  `<name>`

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get?

Comment: A simple search/replace can do what you want without anything special.